# Android - Parse complex json in fragment (listview)

Tags: java, android, json, listview, android-fragments

How can I parse my complex json data inside fragment (listview). I can't all the json data inside fragment.

Error

[image]

Json data

```
{
    "users": [{
        "userId": 1,
        "name": "Dya Vega",
        "profilePhoto": "https://graph.facebook.com/1301454197/picture?type=large",
        "dateMatched": "1/1/2015",
        "distance": "1 miles away",
        "status": "Online",
        "requestMessage": "Hi, can I know you?",
        "like": 234,
        "lastActive": "Active 1 hour ago"
    }, {
        "userId": 2,
        "name": "Esa Ezzatinor",
        "profilePhoto": "https://graph.facebook.com/1269334432/picture?type=large",
        "dateMatched": "1/1/2015",
        "distance": "2 miles away",
        "status": "Online",
        "requestMessage": "Hi, can I know you?",
        "like": 234,
        "lastActive": "Active 2 hour ago"
    }]
}
```

HistoryFragment.java

```
public class HistoryFragment extends Fragment {

...

// Creating volley request obj
        JsonArrayRequest userReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        hidePDialog();

                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {

                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                User user = new User();
                                User.setName(obj.getString("name")); // error here
                                User.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("profilePicture")); // error here
                                User.setLastLogin(obj.getString("lastLogin")); // and here

                                // adding user to users array
                                userList.add(user);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                        // notifying list adapter about data changes
                        // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        hidePDialog();

                    }
                });

...

}
```

User.java (Model/Object)

```
public class User {
    private String name, lastActive, profilePhotoUrl;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String name, String lastActive, String profilePhotoUrl) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lastActive = lastActive;
        this.profilePhotoUrl = profilePhotoUrl;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLastActive() {
        return lastActive;
    }

    public void setLastActive(String lastActive) {
        this.lastActive = lastActive;
    }

    public String getProfilePhotoUrl() {
        return profilePhotoUrl;
    }

    public void setProfilePhotoUrl(String profilePhotoUrl) {
        this.profilePhotoUrl = profilePhotoUrl;
    }
}
```

Comment: just call setters on instance not on the class, ie on user not **U**ser ... it looks like a typo :)

Comment: Adding to above Use GSON, this will do your task easily.

Comment: You check my model in my question :)

Comment: Sorry, my mistakes. User suppose to be user. Damn..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in `User` class all methods are `non-static` but trying to access all method using class name(*static methods only accessed using class name*).

Create class object to access all methods

```
User user = new User();
```

Now use `user` to access all getter/setter methods from User class.

If want to access all methods without creating object using class name as doing currently then add static with all methods in User class.

Comment: I got this: Multiple markers at this line
 - Cannot use this in a static context
 - Line breakpoint:User [line: 20] - 
  setName(String)

Comment: @Dato'MohammadNurdin: I hope you know : `You can access only static variables or methods inside static method`

Answer (score 2):

you should set `methods` to **User** class `Object` like

```
  User user = new User();
  user.setName(obj.getString("name")); 
  user.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("profilePicture")); 
  user.setLastLogin(obj.getString("lastLogin"));
```

You can access all the User class methods only by creating Object of that class.

Comment: what are the differences ?

Comment: You can access all the `User` class methods only by creating `Object` of that class.